# The group action of $S_n$ given a partition of $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

We know that irreducible representations of $S_n$ are given by partitions of $n$. I would like to know if there is a way to explicitly write down the action of some $g \in S_n$ on the representation vector space when being given the given corresponding partition of $n$.

Looking through Fulton and Harris' book I can't see such an expression.

Comment: See http://www.ma.rhul.ac.uk/~uvah099/Maths/Sym/SymGroup2014.pdf .

Comment: @darijgrinberg Which one?

Comment: You are looking for «an expression» but you will only get algorithms and such: you are seriously underestimating the complexity of the representations, methinks.

Comment: You can also find a fairly explicit algorithm/description in Sagan's book *The Symmetric Group*, chapter 2. I believe that the method is the same as in the paper linked above by @darijgrinberg, but I have only glanced at the latter.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Can you link me to even an algorithm which can let me write down the action given a tableux?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Can you may be quickly point me to what part in your link is that algorithm?

Comment: Go to the book, and look at the index!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I don't have an access to any book at this point. If someone can point out the relevant section in Darij's link then it can help. I am skimming through that but I haven't yet spotted any algorithm as such.

Comment: Ah, are you asking for the matrices? If so, see Sagan, "The symmetric group", §2.12, Exercise 11.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Or does your link give an algorithm to find those matrices? (or any other description of the action of the elements when one is given a tableux)

Comment: The link gives in section 6 a construction of a basis of a concrete description of the irreps, from which the matrices can obviously be computed.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez You mean these things called the "standard $\lambda$-polytabloids" form a basis for the irreducible representation given by the partition $\lambda$. So one needs to know how does each group element act on each of these "standard $\lambda$-polytabloids"

Comment: Yes. Once you fix a basis, it is very easy (although quite some work!) to compute explicitly the matrices of the action with respect to the basis. Notice that getting the basis is quite not trivial.

Comment: Well - if I understand by reading that linked article - the baiss is constructed thus :  (1) write down all the standard number fillings in the young diagram for a given partition shape - call any one such filling as $t$ (2) for a given standard filling now create a signed linear sum over all elements of the group which permute the column entries amongst itself (3) Now construct the linear sum of filled tableux formed by acting the thing in (2) on its corresponding filled tableux call it say $e(t)$

Comment: (4) The basis is given by the set of all $e(t)$ where $t$ varies over all possible standard fillings of the tableux shape specified by the partition $\lambda$ - right?

Answer (score 0):

You will find such a construction in a different book by Fulton: "Young tableaux" subtitle "with applications to representation theory and geometry."

Comment: Or in James beautiful little book on the representation of symmetric groups.

Comment: @Mariano I swear by the book in my answer. Fulton is my advisor's advisor, how could I recommend another source?